# Porque al instalar mi programa en electron se reemplaza la db en vez de abrirse con better-sqlite3?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sqlite3, electron

vengo por su ayuda debido a que no logre nada con la ayuda de ChatGPT ni con la documentación.Tengo una app de escritorio con Electron la cual funciona perfectamente excepto por una cosa. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
const { app, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const sqlite3 = require('better-sqlite3');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');

let db;
if (app.isPackaged !== true) {
    const ruta = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..');
    const dbPath = `${ruta}/Minventario.db`;
    db = new sqlite3(dbPath, { verbose: console.log });
} else {
    const ruta = path.join(os.homedir(), 'AppData', 'Local', 'minventario');
    const dbPath = `${ruta}/Minventario.db`;
    db = new sqlite3(dbPath);
};
```

Este se ejecuta al iniciarse la app, pero según la documentación de better-sqlite3 no requiero abrir una conexión ya que detecta de manera automática si existe o no una db, si existe la abre si no la crea, pero por algún motivo al instalar la app de Electron esto no ocurre y reemplaza la db cada vez que instalo, pero extrañamente con el mismo código al abrir la app no se reemplaza y funciona sin problemas.

¿Alguien más a tenido problemas de este tipo que me ayude? La verdad solo me falta resolver este error para poder distribuir mi proyecto y no se que más intentar.

Si hay algún error en la pregunta sean libres de corregir ya que aun me cuesta entender como preguntar correctamente acá.

Edit: Este codigo se ejecuta solo al ejecutar la app y no durante la instalacion, de hecho durante la instalacion no hay configuracion adicional solo la que viene por defecto en electron-forge

Comment: Yo no se especificamente de esto.. pero instalar y ejecutar son 2 cosas muy diferentes... podrias definir que es instalar para vos y que es ejecutar???

Comment: Al igual que el comentario de arriba, no se mucho de esto pero no será que al ejecutar te crea una instancia de la base de datos para desarrollar y al instalar la app crea la instancia de la base de datos para usarse (para el usuario)?

Comment: @gbianchi tecnicamente no hay configuracion de instalacion, pero si de ejecucion inicial, este codigo se ejecuta al iniciar el programa por primera vez y en todas sus ejecuciones siguientes.

Comment: Una ejecucion o mil son iguales... ahora, si la primera vez que se ejecuta, crea la base, quiere decir que no estaba.. no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Bueno luego de buscar informacion descubri que el problema era que
> electron-forge al crear el paquete por defecto crea un paquete que no
> actualiza como tal la app sino que reemplaza sus archivos por ende la
> app anterior era borrada en su totalidad y reemplazada con la nueva,
> la solucion mas sencilla que se me ocurrio es crear la db en una ruta
> diferente a la app, asi cuando se instala una actualizacion esta no
> borra la db ya que no seria una ruta que corresponda a la app por
> defecto.